# Amp img not showing

Tags: html, mobile, amp-html

Example link: http://cinema.popcorntv.it/amp/news/una-mamma-per-amica-un-indizio-conferma-che-luke-e-lorelai/26947

I've a problem with the logo amp-img tag. I served the logo image trought our cloudfront cdn... If i test the page with google ispector and simulate mobile device the logo appear..

googleing the amp link with many smartphone (ios and android) the logo not appear... and the amp page showing only a grey placeholder instead the branding logo.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can see your logo in many smartphones, however if you open this link: http://cinema.popcorntv.it/amp/news/una-mamma-per-amica-un-indizio-conferma-che-luke-e-lorelai/26947#development=1 ,you'll see a warning in the console about 'amp-ad' extension, I suggest you should download this extension chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amp-validator/nmoffdblmcmgeicmolmhobpoocbbmknc?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog to check any problems with amp-html